# What is the best way to hide/show multiple text boxes in different form groups with radio buttons?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, forms

I have a form with multiple form groups which have a yes and no radio buttons each, each form group is a different question that when a user select "yes" it will display a text box that the user would fill with their answer. I found the following solution:

```js
function ShowHideDiv() {
        var chkYes = document.getElementById("chkYes");
        var dvtext = document.getElementById("dvtext");
        dvtext.style.display = chkYes.checked ? "block" : "none";
    }
```

```html
<label for="chkYes">
    <input type="radio" id="chkYes" name="chk" onclick="ShowHideDiv()" />
    Yes
</label>
<label for="chkNo">
    <input type="radio" id="chkNo" name="chk" onclick="ShowHideDiv()" />
    No
</label>
<div id="dvtext" style="display: none">
    Text Box:
    <input type="text" id="txtBox" />
</div>
```

But the Javascript only works with ID's so that would mean I will need to add again the function with the new ID for each different form group to display each different text box. Is there a better way to do this? Is there something I could use to display the text boxes each time the user clicks the yes radio button in each different form group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to add multiple functions you can achieve it by using a single function with an argument like:

```js
function ShowHideDiv(formgrouppno) {
  var chkYes = document.getElementById("chkYes" + formgrouppno);
  var dvtext = document.getElementById("dvtext" + formgrouppno);
  dvtext.style.display = chkYes.checked ? "block" : "none";
}
```

```html
<h3>Form grp 1</h3>
<label for="chkYes1">
    <input type="radio" id="chkYes1" name="chk1" onclick="ShowHideDiv(1)" />
    Yes
</label>
<label for="chkNo1">
    <input type="radio" id="chkNo1" name="chk1" onclick="ShowHideDiv(1)" />
    No
</label>
<div id="dvtext1" style="display: none">
  Text Box 1:
  <input type="text" id="txtBox1" name="txtbox1" />
</div><br/>
<hr/>


<h3>Form grp 2</h3>
<label for="chkYes">
    <input type="radio" id="chkYes2" name="chk2" onclick="ShowHideDiv(2)" />
    Yes
</label>
<label for="chkNo">
    <input type="radio" id="chkNo2" name="chk2" onclick="ShowHideDiv(2)" />
    No
</label>
<div id="dvtext2" style="display: none">
  Text Box 2:
  <input type="text" id="txtBox2" name="txtbox2" />
</div><br/>
<hr/>

<h3>Form grp 2</h3>
<label for="chkYes">
    <input type="radio" id="chkYes3" name="chk3" onclick="ShowHideDiv(3)" />
    Yes
</label>
<label for="chkNo">
    <input type="radio" id="chkNo3" name="chk3" onclick="ShowHideDiv(3)" />
    No
</label>
<div id="dvtext3" style="display: none">
  Text Box 3:
  <input type="text" id="txtBox3" name="txtbox3" />
</div><br/>
<hr/>
```

Note: You can add as many as text boxes and all will be handled by only one javascript function. Watch carefully at how i defined onclick functions, name and id attributes for radio buttons and how they will be used in javascript function.

This is using pure javascript but if you use jquery than it will be easier, i hope this can help.

Answer (score -1):

Its very simple with jQuery

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('input[name="chk"]').change(function(){
        if($(this).val() == 'yes'){
          $('#dvtext').show();
        }else{
          $('#dvtext').hide();
        }
    });
 
});
```

```html
 
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <label for="chkYes">
    <input type="radio" name="chk" value="yes" />
    Yes
</label>
<label for="chkNo">
    <input type="radio" name="chk" value="no" />
    No
</label>
<div id="dvtext" style="display: none">
    Text Box:
    <input type="text" id="txtBox" />
</div>
```